# The dupe-closure search box misses documents found by the regular site search

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, search

Today, as I attempted to close a question as a dupe, I discovered that the search box on the dupe-target selection popup seems to have gone from dodgy to useless.  I normally try searching there first, as when it works, it's pretty convenient.  Today, however, it seems unable to find much of anything, including for queries to which the main site search returns multiple relevant hits.

For example, the main site search turns up many good hits for the query "definition vs declaration [c]", with the top one being a very highly-voted and relevant classic.  The dupe-closure search, however, returns *no hits at all* for that query ("Your search returned no matches; please try a different search").  In fact, it doesn't return any hits for "definition" or "declaration" alone, either, though it does seem to know what to do with just "[c]".

I have only guesses as to why this might be happening, but it is clear at least that the main site search widget is handling my query differently than the dupe-closure search widget is doing.  It shouldn't.  At least not without letting me opt out.

Comment: Indeed, I tried to find a popular dupe today that I have used before and know the criteria well and it failed. A standard search found it with no difficulty.

Comment: So, @CodyGray, if by adding the [vote-to-close] tag you are suggesting that this question is off-topic, then would you mind commenting about that?  This is intended as a bug report concerning a behavioral regression on the site, which I thought would be on-topic for meta.

Comment: @John No, no. It's not off-topic at all. The question is completely welcome here, and I understood it perfectly. The [vote-to-close] tag means that you're asking something related to voting to close. This is Meta, so the tags are kinda weird. They still describe the *content* of your question.

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate of the other one. It appears the issue was fixed by the change that Nick rolled out. I'm able to see questions in the duplicate close dialog now.